# PROXY ERROR establishing connection with client/server application in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, proxy, client-server, econnrefused

I'm currently working on something involving AWS and has a theme based around seeing thoughts from users as well as having the option to create thoughts, and I've encountered a proxy error while trying to establish a connection between the frontend(localhost:3000) and the server(localhost:3001). There's a specified proxy in the package.json file for the frontend, but it
still doesn't seem to establish a connection and the data I have within the server section doesn’t show up at all when I run my code. Here is an example of an error that's occurs when I run the application:

[Proxy Error Statement]
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /api/users from localhost:3000 to http://localhost:3001/.
See https://nodejs.org/api/errors.html#errors_common_system_errors for more information (ECONNREFUSED).

I've attempted to specify IP addresses instead of using localhost and implemented proxies in both the client and server packages. Unfortunately, no resolution has emerged, and I find myself having the same conclusion.

Can check my repository on GitHub for further details: https://github.com/ajosuebn/aws-Thought